# HIve CLI doesn't support MySql style data import to tables

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

Why can't we import data into hive  CLI as following, The `hive_test` table has `user`, `comments` columns.

```
insert into table hive_test (user, comments) 
value ("hello", "this is a test query");
```

Hive throws following exception in hive CLI

> FAILED: ParseException line 1:28 cannot recognize input near '(' 'user' ',' in select clause

I don't want to import the data through csv file like following for a testing perpose.

```
load data local inpath '/home/hduser/test_data.csv' into table hive_test;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's worth noting that Hive advertises "SQL-like" syntax, rather than actual SQL syntax. There's no particular reason to think that pure SQL queries will actually run on Hive. HiveQL's DML is documented [here on the Wiki](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DML), and does not support the column specification syntax or the `VALUES` clause. However, it does support this syntax:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE tablename1 SELECT ... FROM ...
```

Extrapolating from [these test queries](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/trunk/ql/src/test/queries/clientpositive/insert1.q), you might be able to get something like the following to work:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE hive_test SELECT 'hello', 'this is a test query' FROM src LIMIT 1
```

However, it does seem that Hive is not really optimized for this small-scale data manipulation. I don't have a Hive instance to test any of this on.

Comment: What do you mean by `src`? Any other table name?

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: I think so. Just going from the test case there, but any table should work.

Comment: For anyone still curious: INSERT...VALUES is available starting in Hive 0.14.

Answer (score 0):

I think, it is because `user` is a built-in (Reserved) keyword.

Try this:

```
insert into table hive_test ("user", comments) 
value ('hello', 'this is a test query');
```

Comment: `[]` is invalid in (standard) SQL. You need to use double quotes `"` to quote reserved words

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : I've tried with different column like `insert into table hive_test_table (test_column, comments) value ("hms", "this is a test query");`. No way!

Comment: @KugathasanAbimaran: you need to quote the **column** names with double quotes, not the values. Character values (string literals) have to enclosed in *single* quotes: `insert into table hive_test ("user", comments)  values ('hello', 'this is a test query');` And in standard SQL it should be `values` rather than `value`